# storing checkbox field into database

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

Currently, the checkbox field in the database is stored as ["B"],["C"]. I was wondering if there is anyway possible way to store the checkbox field as BC only.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";

    var role;
});

function savenewuser() {
    var url = serverURL() + "/newadmin.php";
    checklist = new Array();
    $('input:checkbox[name="roles[]"]:checked').each(function() {
        checklist.push($(this).val());
    });

    role = JSON.stringify(checklist);

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            "role": role,
        },
        success: function(arr) {
            _getNewUserResult(arr);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}

<div><label for="rights">Rights</label></div>
<input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="A">Bookings
<input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="B">Incident Booking
<input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="C">Edit User
```

Comment: What is your php code?

Comment: The answer you seek depends entirely on your database schema and your php script. The JavaScript you've posted is interesting but ultimately not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it looks like you're passing the value of `role` directly into the database, rather than using `JSON.stringify` to create `role`, you could just use [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method:

```js
var checklist = ['B', 'C'];
var role = checklist.join('');
console.log(role);
console.log(JSON.stringify(checklist));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Currently you are using JSON.stringify on an array of elements which will give you "["B"],["C"]".

Try using join for an example to make a string of the array before stringify it:

```
role = JSON.stringify(checklist.join(""));
```

Output:

```
"BC"
```

Regards Daniel.